# How to check for lowest IDLE time of specific user if logged on more than one terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, authentication, terminal, grep

If a specific user is logged on more than one terminal, how can I check for the line where the IDLE time is the lowest? 
I used the following command:

```
who -u -H | grep 'user1' | tr -s " " | cut -f '1 4' -d " "
```

And the output is:

```
user1 13:22
user1 13:50
```

That means **user1** is logged on two terminals, and the second column shows the IDLE time. 
I'm working on a shell script and I want to use only the first line because the IDLE time is the lowest.

Comment: `..... | sort -n  | head -n1`

Comment: That works just fine. Thank you :)